# TryParse method returns different results

Tags: c#

I am trying to check a string has numbers or not using "TryParse" method. For number in string "101" it returns "True" and for number in string "20170119000004" it returns "False".

My code:

```
int n;
string maf_seq_no="";
maf_seq_no = "101";
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(maf_seq_no, out n)); //OUTPUT True
maf_seq_no = "20170119000004";
Console.WriteLine(int.TryParse(maf_seq_no, out n)); //OUTPUT False
```

Any idea why different output for numbers?

Comment: n can not hold that value, since it is an int.

Comment: buffer overflow? Try outputting a `long` in your 2nd test case, rather than an `int`.

Comment: If string might hold arbitrary number of digits - it's not proper way to check it (even if use long instead of int).

Comment: The second value you´re trying to parse is to big for an integer, the maximum value an integer can hold is 2,147,483,647

Comment: As a corollary, not all sequences of digits are valid `int`, or valid `long` :-)

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OK thanks, so variable "n" must be "long" right?

Comment: *so variable "n" must be "long" right*. No. It will return the same result from `int.TryParse`. `maf_seq_no` must be equals or less than int `MaxValue`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to check if a `string` is only composed of digits, you can do:

```
string str = "12345";
bool isAllDigits = str.All(char.IsDigit);
```

an `int` can be at max 2147483647 (but it can even be negative!), a `long`  9223372036854775807 (but it can even be negative!). There are unsigned versions that can contain bigger numbers, but still the maximum number of digits is "fixed"!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this returns the correct output

Answer (score 2):

`20170119000004` is not a valid int value. The largest possible int value is `2147483647`. That's why it's returning false.

If you want to check whether a string consists entirely of digits, you can use:

```
var isOnlyNumbers = RegEx.IsMatch(maf_seq_no, "^[0-9]+$");
```

Answer (score 1):

`int.TryParse` returns `false` for `"20170119000004"` because this value higher than `int.MaxValue`.

You can try `long.TryParse` for example.

Comment: Higher than `int.MaxValue`

Answer (score 1):

It returns `false` because `20170119000004` is too large for an `int` (int32). An `int`'s [**maximum value**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.maxvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is `2147483647`, or 2<sup>31</sup> - 1.

Use a [**`long`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ctetwysk.aspx) instead, its maximum value is `9223372036854775807` or
 2<sup>63</sup> - 1.